# php global causing non-object error unless transfered from $GLOBALS

Tags: php, scope, include, global-variables

I have a file that contains a class. I will `include` this file when I need access to the class. I want to declare the class inside the file where the class exists, so that I only have to declare the class once, and only have to `include` the file to use the class.

This works.

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['foo_model'] = new foo_model;
$foo_model = $GLOBALS['foo_model'];
global $foo_model;

Class foo_model
{
    function foo_function() {
        // ect
    }
}
```

This does not work

```
<?php

$foo_model = new foo_model;
global $foo_model;

Class foo_model
{
    function foo_function() {
        // ect
    }
}
```

It causes the error when the class is attempted to be used.

```
Call to a member function foo_function() on a non-object
```

Why do I have to start with `$GLOBALS`, and then turn it into a regular variable and then apply `global`. I thought `$GLOBALS` and `global` were only different in syntax. What does `$GLOBALS` do differently here?

Furthermore, what is the best way to write a file that contains a class, so that I can `include` the file, and use the class, without having to declare the class after including the file, and without using `$GLOBALS`? Is my first code snippet the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would start with the class definition, and then the instantiation.

Comment: If you mean putting `$api_model = new api_model;
global $api_model;` at the bottom of the file, that still pops a non-object error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it this way, it's very bad design. Try using Traits.

But what i see you are trying to do is create class file and load it without including it. That's what the concept of autoloader class is. 
Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

Remember: globals are always problematic, avoid them whenever is possible.

Comment: I haven't heard of Traits before. I'll look into Traits and consider if autoload is correct for my situation, and will get back to you.

Comment: It turns out for my situation, I need to change my code from procedural to object oriented in order for these global issues to disappear. However, your answer was invaluable in reaching this conclusion. I would still like to understand why `GLOBALS` behaves differently than `global` in this case.

Comment: Sorry if i couldn't help you more, but from my understanding and stated at manual, autoloading is exactly what you need - it is the way it was designed so to create classes without including their files.

As of why, global keyword is in deprecation, what is your PHP version? Also, from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php $_GLOBALS is the correct way to use global scope. Also note that from PHP 5.3.0 you need to declare variable with global keyword if you use it inside a function like you did.
Of course changing to OO dispears as when using OO you have all in the same scope

Comment: Just one more thing, as i was reading the manual, there is a note that i think will explain what you want to know: 
"Note: Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function. "

So if i understood  what you were doing, it is exactly what it was happening to you...

Comment: Perhaps. I could refactor things to make it work, but if I would be spending that much time, might as well go OO, which is what I'd prefer.

Comment: I agree, always prefer OO as it is what PHP is evolving to ;)